# Missing 1 required positional argument in Python proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy

I am using [pproxy](https://pypi.org/project/pproxy/) to listen on a http port and use a socks proxy to reach internet. The following command works as expected, since I am able to browse any website by using 127.0.0.1:12345 in my browser's proxy settings.

```
C:\tools>pproxy -l http://127.0.0.1:12345 -r socks5://127.0.0.1:9050
Serving on 127.0.0.1:12345 by http
```

But the following Python script, gives me an error.

```
import asyncio
import pproxy

server = pproxy.Server('http://127.0.0.1:12345')
remote = pproxy.Connection('socks5://127.0.0.1:9050')
args = dict( rserver = [remote],
             verbose = print )

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
handler = loop.run_until_complete(server.start_server(args))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('exit!')

handler.close()
loop.run_until_complete(handler.wait_closed())
loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
loop.close()
```

And the error I get when running the script is:

```
http_accept() missing 1 required positional argument: 'httpget' from 127.0.0.1
```

EDIT: Running it with the debug flag on, I am getting:

```
http_accept() missing 1 required positional argument: 'httpget' from 127.0.0.1
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-5' coro=<stream_handler() done, defined at C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pproxy\server.py:62> exception=TypeError("http_accept() missing 1 required positional argument: 'httpget'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pproxy\server.py", line 74, in stream_handler
    lproto, user, host_name, port, client_connected = await proto.accept(protos, reader=reader, writer=writer, authtable=AuthTable(remote_ip, authtime), reader_cipher=reader_cipher, sock=writer.get_extra_info('socket'), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pproxy\proto.py", line 557, in accept
    ret = await proto.accept(reader, user, **kw)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pproxy\proto.py", line 298, in accept
    return await self.http_accept(user, method, path, None, ver, lines, headers.get('Host', ''), headers.get('Proxy-Authorization'), reply, **kw)
TypeError: http_accept() missing 1 required positional argument: 'httpget'
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace, so we can see which line in your code is causing the error.

Comment: @joao I've edited my question. Thank you.